# Unable to turn off auto-correction on HTC one

Tags: keyboard, htc-one-x, auto-correct

I just received a HTC one.  I cannot turn off the autocorrect for 'Word Prediction' (under prediction preference) in the > HTC Sense Input Setting > Advanced section. The words are gray colored and the checked box does not respond. Other functions I can turn on and off.

Any suggestions on how to disable this function would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have to turn off the keyboard trace. Unfortunately  through a very poor design, you can't have trace without the autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

If using the stock keyboard: `Settings > Language & Keyboard > HTC Sense Input > Advanced > Word prediction`. Uncheck the box.